# Do silent door latches exist?

Tags: doors, noise-reduction

Is there such a thing as a silent (or muffled) door latch? The doors inside my house make a very loud click when the latch snaps into the frame when closing the door.

Comment: You're absolutely right. My searching skills are apparently lacking. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please continue to ask questions.